# Fileinput not defined

Tags: asp.net, reactjs

I'm trying to learn React on Asp.net. I'm trying to create a file upload page but it seems like Fileinput is missing.

> MyFileUploader.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'


export class MyFileUploader extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.uploadFile = this.uploadFile.bind(this);
    }

    uploadFile(event) {
        let file = event.target.files[0];
        console.log(file);

        if (file) {
            let data = new FormData();
            data.append('file', file);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <span>
            <input type="file"
                name="myFile"
                onChange={this.uploadFile} />
        </span>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<FileInput />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Sorry, missed to add the error...

I get
"(ESLint) 'FileInput' is not defined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ReactDOM.render(<FileInput />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

ReactDOM.render takes two arguments first argument is React component which we have created either class or functional component. In your case its class component `class MyFileUploader` so your component name is `MyFileUploader` and you are passing first argument to `ReactDOM.render` FileInput. you have to either pass

```
ReactDOM.render(<MyFileUploader />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

or you have to change your component name

```
class FileInput
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Thought "FileInput" was some sort of component. Realize now how everything work. :)